# sans serif font with siunitx

Tags: fonts, siunitx, sans-serif

My students found this problem, which I could not solve. The percent is always printed in the serif font.

[image]

Here is a test code:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % T1 Schrift Encoding
\usepackage{lmodern}  % Latin Modern
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{%
  mode = math,
  detect-family,
  detect-weight,  
  exponent-product = \cdot,
  number-unit-separator=\text{\,},
  output-decimal-marker={\text{,}},
  math-rm=\mathsf,
  text-rm=\sffamily,
}

\begin{document}
\sffamily\noindent
Text \SI{1.23}{\%} and further text.
\begin{table}[H]
\sffamily
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\SI{1.23}{\%} & 1,23\,\%
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why didn't you introduce the student who found the problem to tex.sx and let them ask this question themselves? `;)`

Comment: I did that, but I also want to get my lecture finished, so that I can publish the slides. And the discussion on how to get help is a topic for the next and last lecture next week...

Comment: why the `\,` before the `\%`? That should not be nessary

Comment: That was a copy-paste error. I know that it should not be there. I have removed it from the code

Answer (score 44, accepted):

From page 5 of the siunitx manual:

> By default, all text is typeset in the current upright, serif math font. This can be changed by setting the appropriate options: `\sisetup{detect-all}` will use the current font for typesetting.

Thus, just replace the options `detect-family` and `detect-weight` in the preamble's `\sisetup{...}` instruction with `detect-all`, and your students will be all set.

Incidentally, if you run `\addto\extrasngerman{\sisetup{locale=DE}}` after loading the `babel` package with the option `ngerman`, you don't have to specify the options `output-decimal-marker={\text{,}}` `exponent-product = \cdot`, and `number-unit-separator=\text{\,}` explicitly while loading the `siunitx` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern} 

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\addto\extrasngerman{\sisetup{locale=DE}}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-all} % note: just one option still needs to be specified

\begin{document}
\sffamily
\SI{1.23}{\%}

1,23\,\%
\end{document}
```

Comment: But `\SI{1.23}{\text{\%}}` is very counter-intuitive. So I am still looking for a better solution.

Comment: Ok, `detect-all` solves the problem. But i wonder why this is not default?

Comment: Might be because some of these extra features slows down the parsing. So only enabling them when needed may be quite useful. For example typesetting large tables with `siunitx` soon become very slow, I have some tables that can take 10 sec to compile (each), rather anoying.

Comment: The `detect-all` switch actually turns on four separate `detect-...` conditions. The one that your students were missing was `detect-mode`. The two other switches that were already set by them (`detect-family`, `detect-weight`) remain turned on, of course, when they're superseded by `detect-all`. See pp. 17-19 of the manual for more details.

Comment: Remember the standard settings in `siunitx` are supposed to follow the 'rules': units should be given in an upright roman font irrespective of the surrounding text. (Mathematically, `\mathrm{m}` and `\mathsf{m}` are not the same thing, hence the presumption that even the most basic font changes should be ignored.)

Comment: @daleif It's not so long ago that TeX took minutes for each page of basic text :-)

Comment: @daleif I have some ideas on a 'fast math' mode for printing, which may help in some cases. This will need a bit of testing: expect a version by e-mail at some point!

Comment: @JW sounds good.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that you are assuming that `%` in `\mathsf` 'looks' sanserif, but it does not

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\mathsf{\%}$
\end{document}
```

Either stick to text mode for units

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup
  {
    math-rm=\mathsf,
    text-rm=\sffamily
  }
\begin{document}
\SI{1.23}{\%}
\end{document}
```

force text mode for this particular case

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup
  {
    mode = math,
    math-rm=\mathsf
  }
\begin{document}
\SI{1.23}{\text{\%}}
\end{document}
```

or use the symbolic mode and an appropriate definition

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup
  {
    mode = math,
    math-rm=\mathsf
  }
\DeclareSIUnit{\percent}{\text{\%}}
\begin{document}
\SI{1.23}{\percent}
\end{document}
```

In all cases, note that extra spacing should not be added to the unit part: there is an automatic space between the number and the unit.

Answer (score 4):

As already have been mentioned the source of the problem is that you typeset the percent in mathmode and assumed that `\mathsf{\%}` gives a sans serif percent. But the percentchar has mathcode hex 25, the `\math...` commands affect only chars with math code > hex 7000. You would get the expected result if you would change the mathcode:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern} 

\begin{document}
$\mathbf{\% a}\mathsf{\% a} \% a$

\mathcode`\%="7025
$\mathbf{\% a}\mathsf{\% a} \% a$

\end{document}
```