# siunitx does not scale \percent for beamer

Tags: siunitx, scaling

I recently started using `siunitx` and came across the following problem:

In my beamer slides `\percent` ist not scaled according to the definition in the preamble. Other units are scaled correctly. Interestingly, this works fine for other document classes, for example `article`.

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[scaled=0.92]{helvet}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
    1\% vs. \SI{1}{\percent}

    1m vs. \SI{1}{\metre}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: The default setup for `siunitx` uses math mode: compare the output with `$\mathrm{\%}$`

Comment: @Teepeemm Thanks! You are right, the title was missing a "not".

Comment: @JosephWright Indeed, $\mathrm{\%}$ also yields an unscaled %. I'll try to find out more tomorrow. Thank you!

Comment: It seems that beamer always uses the default font family for certain symbols in math mode. You can see that by changing the family, for example to helvetica, and comparing $\%$ to \% (the same happens for \&). So my problem is not at all related to siunitx or scaling. 

Should I open a new question or modify the existing question?

Comment: Yes, the percent char doesn't react to \mathrm or \mathsf as letters do, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35292/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you very much! The option detect-all from your link solved my problem plus I now understand the unexpected behaviour. Do you want to post your comment as an answer, so I can accept it as solution?