# beamer: sans-serif / serif question related to siunitx

Tags: beamer, siunitx

- I puzzled today for an hour to get the unit sans-serif.
- I found that `\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}` helps but I am not sure if this is the correct way.
- Question: Is it logical that I need `\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}` in order to have the units sans-serif?

[image]

```
% Based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66713/
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{noto}
\usepackage{arevmath}
%\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif} % <-- Un/Comment to see change

\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{%
    per-mode = fraction,
    fraction-function = \sfrac,
    }

\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
  Text appears in \textbf{sans-serif} font

  $x,2y,3z$ appears in \textbf{sans-serif} font

  $\SI{1}{\metre\per\second}$ units appears in \textbf{serif} font, would like it to be sans-serif
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

**Edit:** I now believe my question is a duplicate of [sans serif font with siunitx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35287/).

Comment: Add `detect-all` in `sisetup` will do.

Comment: @TeddyvanJerry Thanks for the reply. Will test tomorrow. If memory serves me well then I tried that already but I will try again to be sure.

Comment: Here is my [test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIeKy.jpg) with Ubuntu + texlive 2021.

Comment: @TeddyvanJerry It worked, not sure why I did not solve it on my own (maybe the day was too long at work). You can convert your comment into an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is discussed in [sans serif font with siunitx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35287/234654),
`detect-all` in `sisetup` will make the unit in sans serif font as is the text in the document.

Here is the test result.
[image: Test Result]

Comment: The confusing part was that in `beamer` the other math stuff already was sans-serif.

Comment: Indeed, maybe there are many logics behind how `siunitx` *detects* and *decides* which font family to use.